# How can I use MutationObserver on multiple nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

The following code allows me to listen for class changes on a single node:

```
var target = $(".right-border")[0]

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
console.log(“Change”)
  });
  });

  var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

 observer.observe(target, config);
```

If I have a grid of divs, for example, and each div on the right border has a class of right-border, how can I listen for changes on each one? I know that I could create multiple variables:

```
var target2 = $(".right-border")[1]
var target3 = $(".right-border")[2]
```

But is there a more efficient way of selecting each node? Is it possible to use a for loop somewhere in the above code that targets each div with a class of right-border?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `each` method to iterate over all matching DOM nodes and observe its mutations. The code is almost what you already have - notice that `target = this` which is how each node is targeted.

```
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

$(".right-border").each(function () {
  var target = this;
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log("Change")
    });
  });

  observer.observe(target, config);
});
```

Comment: How would OP be able to call `.disconnect()` on the `MutationObserver()` instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate `.right-border` elements using `.each()`, call function to create `MutationObserver` for each element, store the instances of `MutationObserver` within an array of objects where index of element in collection references `MutationObserver` instance for that element.

```
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

var observers = [];

function setObserver(target, index) {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log("Change")
    });
  });
  observer.observe(target, config);
  observers.push({[index]: observer});
}

$(".right-border").each(function(index, el) {
  setObserver(el, index)
});
```

Storing of instances of `MutationObserver` is for purpose of calling `.disconnect()` on a specific `MutationObserver` instance if needed; for example

```
var observer = observers.find(function(el) {
  return +Object.keys(el).pop() === 1
});

observer.disconnect();
```

or

```
var observer = observers.filter(function(el) {
  return +Object.keys(el).pop() === 1
});

observer.pop().disconnect();
```